# How to find the annotated values from Jar file

Tags: java, reflection, jar

How to find the annotated values from Jar file.

I have the Project named 'sample' containing 'Test' class in it as shown below

```
@Description(name = "foo", description = "bar")
public class Test {

    //////

}
```

Jar file is created from this project 'sample.jar' How to find the annotated values from Jar file.

I have been provided with 'sample.jar'  and Test.java contains annotation this info is provided.

**Note: In the process of finding this i am not supposed to add 'Sample' Project as depended to my project.**

Tried below code works when i have 'Test' class in class path.
I want to know how to get value with out adding 'Test' to classpath

```
Class aClass = Test.class;
Annotation annotation = aClass.getAnnotation(Description.class);

if(annotation instanceof Description){
    Description myAnnotation = (Description) annotation;
    System.out.println("name: " + myAnnotation.name());
    System.out.println("value: " + myAnnotation.description());
}
```

Comment: There must be some reason you've tagged this with reflection, did you try something on that path?

Comment: Involves reflection concept so tagged

Comment: But then what have you tried using reflection?

Comment: 'Sample.jar' added to class-path in my java program  and used JAVA reflection API to read class properties.  But i want to know without adding to class path how to achive

Comment: Do share what you've tried in the question and then preferably ask what didn't work for you.

Comment: edited question with the what i tired

Comment: @GaneshRaoB Did you ever get a satisfactory answer to this?  I want to do a similar thing where I have an app watching my Tomcat server, and every time a new app is added to the server I want the watching app to scan it for any REST service functionality, and then present that new app (or updated old app) in a REST listing.

Answer (score 0):

Set ClassPath with sample.jar and in program use JAVA reflection API to read class properties. Find guidance from below URL:

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/annotations.html

Comment: I don't want to add 'sample.jar'  class path to my java class